# How to subtract a numeric value stored in a column from a timestamp in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to subtract a numeric value from a timestamp without time zone in postgresql.

I have a table with the columns start_date, end_date and hour_spent.
start_date and end_date are timestamps without time zone and hour_spent is numeric (10,2).

When I try, I get the error: 
operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone - numeric

hour_spent contains values such as 1.00, 2.50, 3.75 etc.

I've tried to cast hour_spent but get a different error. I've seen examples with 'interval' but I can't seem to use that either

```
UPDATE table
SET start_date = end_date - hour_spent
WHERE start_date IS NULL;
```

I expect the start_date to equal the end_date - the number of hours the hour_spent column represents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`make_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.14.5.2.2.23.1.1) and convert the hours to seconds:

```
UPDATE table
   SET start_date = end_date - make_interval(secs => hour_spent * 24 * 60)
WHERE start_date IS NULL;
```